# List control not visible after adding in Sitecore SPEAK UI

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.5, sitecore-speak-ui

I am fairly new to Sitecore and I am trying to add a list control in Sitecore Speak. While I am able to add a List control and bind a Search data source to it, It is not visible in the page when I run the page. I am not sure what is going on.
Below is the screenshot of the Page layout. 
I am using Sitecore 7.5 with Sitecore Rocks version 1.4. 
[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SUCb.png)

Answer (score 1):

Does the Datasource item you have the list control databound to `SearchDataSource` in this case have any data?

You can debug  in the browser console using `Sitecore.Speak.App.DataSource.viewModel.Items()` I believe as long as you have your webpage in debug mode and using this query string `?sc_debug=1`.

If not update the `SearchDataSource` components to perform and return the data you wish to bind. The `SearchDataSource` component will have a few options to set the search you wish to perform.

You shouldn't need a datasource in this case as your data is coming from the `Items` property which is bound to the datasource control.

Comment: The SearchDataSource is bound to a text box which has a default text. I noticed that when i run the page with ?sc_debug=1 I cannot access Sitecore.Speak.App.DataSource.viewModel.Items() or Sitecore.app . It throws an error saying "Sitecore is not defined" and the default require.js/sitecorify.css files are not found. I am not sure if this is related to the List Control not displaying.

Comment: Can you post your PageCode and a screen shot of your SPEAK page layout from ROCKS so i can have a look for you?